# How to use vue-router in a reusable method

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I’m trying to be able to reuse my piece of code where I need it in my app. This piece of code makes conditions on the path of vue-router.

To do this, I created a file "utils.js" :

```
const util = {
  nextStepAtelier () {
    if (this.$route.path.includes(this.user.event_1.slug)) {
      this.$router.push(`/events/${this.user.event_1_2.slug}/step-1`)
    }

    if (this.$route.path.includes(this.user.event_1_2.slug)) {
      this.$router.push(`/games/game-1/step-1`)
    }

  }
};

export default util;
```

And in my `step-3.vue`, I call my `nextStepAtelier()` like that :

```
import util from '~/utils/utils'
export default {
   computed: {
          user() {
              return this.$store.getters['auth/user']
          }
        },
   methods: {
            nexstStep() {
                util.nextStepAtelier();
            }
        }
}
```

It doesn't work. I have errors related to view-router `Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`. It looks like it is not properly analyzing vue-router.

I specify that when I make this code directly in `step-3.vue`, it works

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `this` is different inside your util object, you can have nextStepAtelier accept the router instance as a parameter then call it with `util.nextStepAtelier(this.$router)`

Then you can access the current route with `router.currentRoute` (instead of `this.$route`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the router, you don't have access to the global `$router` inside your js file. Just put on the top of the file:
`import router from './router.js'` (or whatever the path is)
then change `$router` to `router` (remove "this")

Comment: Thank you @Michael, I have a problem with `$route` (no $router), it can't find the `path`. For `push()`, it works but I don't know how to access `.path` with `router`.

Comment: not sure I fully understand you but you can simply give it a name if you have some issue with the path (which is better practice imo)